# Check Email Exists with CodeIgniter & jQuery Validation Plugin always returns false

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

This is my **[reference link](http://www.joshuawinn.com/check-if-email-username-exists-with-codeigniter-and-jquery-validation/)**

I am trying to implement Email exist check using jQuery Validation plugin & CodeIgniter.
Backend: MySQL

My Database table users contains id (auto increment, primary key, integer field) and email (varchar). This table stores email ids.

I am getting the jQuery response. So it kinda works. But the function always returns TRUE. I don't know why. Even when I enter an email id that's not in the database table, I get that 'Email Id already in use' message which means the model function returns TRUE always. I tried JSON encoding the returned value, but it was useless. Everything looks perfect, don't know where I made mistake.

**My Form**:

```
<?php $attributes = array('name' => 'formed', 'id' => 'formed' ,'method'=>'POST' ,'action' => 'echo base_url()' ); 
echo form_open('home/myController', $attributes);  ?>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *">
</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**jQuery Validation**

```
$('#formed').validate(
 {

  rules: {
    email:{
        email: true,
        required: true,
        remote: 
          {
                url: base_url+"home/register_email_exists",
                type: "post",
                data: 
                {
                    email: function(){ return $("#email").val(); }
                    ,csrf_test_name : csrf_token
                }
          }                         
    }
   },
  messages: {
        email: 
         {
                remote: 'Email Id already in use.'
         }
  }, 
    highlight: function(element) {
          $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
     },
     success: function(element) {
      element
     .text('').addClass('valid')
     .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
});
```

**My Controller Function:**

```
 function register_email_exists()
    {
        if (array_key_exists('email',$_POST)) 
        {
         if ( $this->Home_model->email_exists2($this->input->post('email')) == TRUE ) 
          {
            //echo json_encode(FALSE);
            echo 'false';
        } 
       else 
        {
            //echo json_encode(TRUE);
            echo 'true';
        }
     }
   }
```

**My Model Function:**

```
    function email_exists2($email)
   {
     $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
     { 
       return TRUE; 
     } 
    else 
     { 
       return FALSE; 
     }
   }
```

FYI, I have included .js files for jQuery validation plugin. Also don't bother about the CSRF token for now. It works.

Comment: are trying to check unique email address?

Comment: Yep. If the user enters an already existing email id, a message should be shown. @Khairul Islam

Comment: for checking unique field there is a validation rule in codeigniter. `is_unique[table.field]`

Comment: This is the AJAX method. @Khairul Islam

Comment: so what! just validate your email in the controller with this validation rule and if validation runs false then return that error message to your view and show.

Comment: Yes. You hit the bull's eye. @Khairul Islam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from controller return statement:

```
function register_email_exists()
    {
        if (array_key_exists('email',$_POST)) 
        {
         if ( $this->Home_model->email_exists2($this->input->post('email')) == TRUE ) 
          {
            //echo json_encode(FALSE);
            echo false;
        } 
       else 
        {
            //echo json_encode(TRUE);
            echo true;
        }
     }
   }
```